# Cordova Custom Plugin "Arguments to path.join must be strings"

Tags: android, git, android-intent, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm attempting to update the plugin found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447557/phonegap-how-to-trigger-media-scanner-after-creating-file) so that it works with cordova 3.4.0.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Xul13/cordova-mediascanner-plugin)

When I attempt to add the plugin to my project from the top level project folder I get the error:

```
cordova plugin add "https://github.com/Xul13/cordova-mediascanner-plugin"
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/Xul13/cordova-mediascanner-plugin" via git clone

Installing org.xul13.scanmedia (android)
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
TypeError: Uh oh!
Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at f (path.js:204:15)
    at Object.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:209:40)
    at module.exports.source-file.install (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\
    at Object.ActionStack.process (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\util\act
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:415:20)
    at C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:354:20
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\brycem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
```

I assume it's just a simple typo in the plugins.xml file but haven't found anything when comparing it to other working repositories.

Comment: I've somehow resolved the issue. One of the changes I made since asking this question seems to have fixed the problem, but I'm not sure what it was.  I just recently tried deleting the old plugin from my project and re-adding it and it worked. My biggest hunch is leaning towards the package name and the android package value. I don't really want to accept this as an answer because I'm not sure what fixed it. When in doubt make sure you delete all old file remnants from the plugin folder when it fails to compile.